# How to create descriptor watch-only wallet with bitcoin-cli in Bitcoin Core 0.21?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, output-script-descriptors

Using only command line (no GUI), how can I create watch only wallet based on descriptor and get first unused address?

This is the descriptor:

> "wpkh([00000000/84h/0h/0h]xpub6DP....xyz/0/*)#checksum"

this is the bitcoin-cli command to list addresses based on this descriptor:

> ./bitcoin-cli deriveaddresses
> "wpkh([00000000/84h/0h/0h]xpub6DP....xyz/0/*)#checksum" "[0,2]"

How to create actuall watch only wallet so that I can get automatically first unused address?

Answer (score 3):

First create a descriptor wallet with `createwallet`:

```
bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name=mywallet descriptors=true
```

This will make a descriptor wallet named `mywallet`.

Then import a descriptor into that wallet using `importdescriptors:

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=mywallet importdescriptors '[{"desc": "wpkh([00000000/84h/0h/0h]xpub6DP....xyz/0/*)#checksum", "range": [0, 1000], "timestamp": "now", "internal": false, "watchonly": true, "active": true}]
```

This will import the descriptor with an initial keypool of 1000. Any new bech32 addresses you request (with `getnewaddress` or from the GUI) will come from this descriptor.

Comment: The second command ends with error: "Cannot import descriptor without private keys to a wallet with private keys enabled".

Comment: Ah, the first command must contain:  ddisable_private_keys=true

Comment: ./bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name=mywallet descriptors=true disable_private_keys=true